# How to make WPF web browser application scale to screen size in 125% windows display settings?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have developed a wpf web browser application. It is rendering on full screen in IE when windows display settings are at 100%. But when windows display settings are at 125% application is getting scaled and not rendering at full screen in IE.

[WPF web browser application at 100% windows display settings.It is rendering UI perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QLAS.png)

[WPF web browser application at 125% windows display settings.It is not rendering UI to full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dPJ1.png)

In my xaml design i am  using following as page height and width:

Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"
 Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"

As per the insights I have been able to gather at 125% windows display setting the resolution of screen is reduced that is why it is not able to scale to full screen. But I am not  able to find the solution for the same.

Any help would be much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: A web browser decides for itself how it scales its output.  Maybe you just need to press Ctrl-+ to make it smarter.

Answer (score 0):

WPF Web Browser applications should be able to use the full screen, even if monitor scaling is used.

One possible problem is that you're setting the Height and Width manually. Instead, I would recommend you to remove the Width and Height properties from the page. The same applies to your controls: Instead of setting their widths manually, place them in Grid's columns and make the columns fill relative amounts of the screen.

Here's a simple sample app:

> ```
> <Page x:Class="WpfBrowserApp1.Page1"
>   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
>   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
>
>   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
>   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfBrowserApp1"
>   d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
>   Title="Page1">
> <Grid>
>     <Border Background="Red"/>
> </Grid> 
> </Page>
> ```

When run with display scaling 100%, it fills the whole space:

[image: 100% wpf scaling]

And when run with 125%, it still correctly fills the screen:

[image: 125% wpf scaling]